# How is the calculation of the cost of using DocumentDB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

Interested in the question of how the calculation of the cost of using NoSQL databases DocumentDB in Microsoft Azure.

The calculator for calculating the value of a field *"number of collections"* on which, in fact, is multiplied by the total cost. How I understood in tariffs are the prices of 10Gb (2 rubles / hour).

- So, if I have, say, a collection of at 10GB, and 50 pieces of
  collections 200MB, ¿what will be the final check?
- rubles \ hour or subject of number of collections: 100 rubles \ hour?
- if I take, say, 10GB and 1GB, whether it affects the final cost of services, or they rounded up?

Interested in the answers of those who have already used this service.

Comment: This is off-topic for StackOverflow. I'll just tell you that you have complicated a very simple pricing scheme (which is clearly described on Azure's pricing page). You pay per collection, regardless of amount of storage you use. The only variable is your performance tier. You should be able to figure it all out from there.

Answer (score -1):

DocumentDB charges per collection (which includes 10GB of storage and an amount of provisioned throughput depending on performance tier).

You can find DocumentDB pricing details here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/documentdb/